# Nginx server block for multiple subdomains

Tags: nginx, configuration, hostname

I have the following hostname structure:

`main.domain.com` is the main subdomain and is static; any other subdomain is dynamic `*.domain.com`

The root directory is the same for all hostnames.

**Now what happens:** When I access `fruit.domain.com` its redirecting me to 
`main.domain.com`, but it should actually stay on `fruit.domain.com`.

**My configs:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name main.domain.com *.domain.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl spdy;

    server_name main.domain.com *.domain.com;

    root /home/www/app
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$host`[[docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24host)] in place of `$server_name`.